# Simulate Groupby Rollup in Java

Tags: java, sql, java-8

I have an `ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>` which have data like database table. I want to calculate Subtotal an grand total of members in Java it self. Same functionality can be achieved in SQL by GroupBY Rollup/Cube.
I wrote a function to calculate GroupBy Cube.

```
public static List<Map<String, Object>> applyGroupBy(List<LevelDetail> dimensionColumns, List<MeasureDetail> numericColumns, List<Map<String, Object>> resultset) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> resultsetNew = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Map<String, List<Double>> grandTotalMap = new HashMap<String, List<Double>>();
    for (LevelDetail levelDetail : dimensionColumns) {
        Stream<Map<String, Object>> stream = resultset.stream();
        stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get(levelDetail.getName()), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(m -> m, Collectors.toList()))).forEach((g, r) -> {
            Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            row.put(levelDetail.getName(), g);
            for (MeasureDetail measureDetail : numericColumns) {
                DoubleStream valueStream = r.stream().mapToDouble(p -> {
                    p.put(levelDetail.getName() + "_nb_grouping", 0);
                    resultsetNew.add(p);
                    return Double.parseDouble(p.get(measureDetail.getName()) != null ? p.get(measureDetail.getName()).toString() : "0");
                });
                Double value = getAggregatedResult(valueStream, measureDetail.getMeasure_rollup_expr());
                row.put(measureDetail.getName(), value);
                if (dimensionColumns.indexOf(levelDetail) == 0) {
                    if (!grandTotalMap.containsKey(measureDetail.getName())) {
                        grandTotalMap.put(measureDetail.getName(), new ArrayList<Double>());
                    }
                    grandTotalMap.get(measureDetail.getName()).add(value);
                }
            }
            row.put(levelDetail.getName() + "_nb_grouping", 0);
            for (LevelDetail ld : dimensionColumns) {
                if (!ld.getName().equals(levelDetail.getName())) {
                    row.put(ld.getName() + "_nb_grouping", 1);
                    row.put(ld.getName(), null);
                }
            }
            resultsetNew.add(row);
        });
    }
    Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (LevelDetail levelDetail : dimensionColumns) {
        row.put(levelDetail.getName(), null);
        row.put(levelDetail.getName() + "_nb_grouping", 1);
    }
    for (MeasureDetail measureDetail : numericColumns) {
        Double value = getAggregatedResult(grandTotalMap.get(measureDetail.getName()).stream().mapToDouble((i) -> (Double) i), measureDetail.getMeasure_rollup_expr());
        row.put(measureDetail.getName(), value);
    }
    resultsetNew.add(row);
    resultset = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(new LinkedHashSet<Map<String, Object>>(resultsetNew));
    resultsetNew.clear();
    resultsetNew.addAll(resultset);
    return resultsetNew;
}

private static final String AVG = "avg";
private static final String MIN = "min";
private static final String MAX = "max";

private static Double getAggregatedResult(DoubleStream ds, String agg) {
    switch (agg.toLowerCase()) {
    case AVG:
        return ds.average().getAsDouble();
    case MIN:
        ds.min().getAsDouble();
    case MAX:
        ds.max().getAsDouble();
    default:
        return ds.sum();
    }
}
```

I want to write a method which would group by Rollup. It can be parametrized to same function whether to group by Rollup or Cube.

Comment: If SQL is your inspiration, you should really be looking into generalising `ROLLUP` and `CUBE` via `GROUPING SETS`. That will probably also simplify your generalised algorithm...

Comment: You are missing `return` on the `min` and `max` aggregation and `sum` will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

When working with free software SGBDs which are not as powerful as the commercial ones, sometimes one has to implement certain features inside Java code. The rollup seems to be a subset of the cube query. So to get a rollup, you would have to remove some rows from your cube query and some partial totals. In a concrete case this could be rather easy, but generalizing it may take some time to discover exactly which rows should be removed and which algorithm could perform it in every case.